# Webcam Video Capture using Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, directshow, video-capture

I am trying to create an application to capture a snapshot using a webcam.

I have been able to accomplish this using WIA, but this solution becomes unstable when ran on Windows 7 with a camera that has a resolution of more than 1.3 megapixels.  We are coding for a tablet computer that has a built in webcam with 2.0 megapixels.

I am not opposed to using direct show, but I would like to stay away from .net.

I have searched high and low for a solution and I can not get the directshow examples from the windows platform sdk or directx 9.0 to even compile on Visual Studio 6.0.  I have also had no luck OpenCV.

Is there anyone that could point me in the direction of a tutorial that might get me started down the right path?

Thanks

Comment: Your compiler is from the previous century.  Time to upgrade.  The VS2010 Express edition is free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is [videoinput](https://github.com/ofTheo/videoInput) lib that wraps directshow, it's the same lib used by openCV.

If that isn't good enough then the AMCAP sample in the multimedia/directshow dir of the Microsoft SDK shows how to run a camera in directshow

ps. as Hans said you should update the compiler,VC++6 is little old. There is a [free version](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) of their latest vs2010.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  In researching the errors I got when trying to compile the videoinput lib, I was able to determine that Microsoft was phasing out VC++6 support with DirectX 9, I did find a work around and feel that I am stumbling down the right path, now.  As far as updating the compiler, I would like to, but I am working on a very large legacy project, started about 15 years ago... I am new to c++, but the other developers on the project tell me that humongous changes would have to be made to our existing code to get it to build on anything else.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Eidsonator - we feel your pain ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/VideoImageGrabber.aspx) tutorial excellent and it is so simple. I found it worked on XP and win7 with an old webcam and a new one.

I used the second example which is a semi-directshow one, but bypasses most of directshow.
You do need to add error handling though.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/VideoImageGrabber.aspx